# React class methods

Tags: reactjs

I´m building a React calculator, and I´m trying to make a click handler event that will handle all the calculation operations. I keep getting a error when compiling. I´ve tried everything, but I can´t seem to solve it. I think I´m binding the method wrong inside the class, but I am not sure (the “Button” is a different functional component).

App class

```
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: []}

 }
render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display id="display" value={this.state.value} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="zero" value={'0'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="one" value={'1'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="two" value={'2'}/>
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="three" value={'3'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="four" value={'4'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="five" value={'5'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="six" value={'6'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="seven" value={'7'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="eight" value={'8'}  />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="nine" value={'9'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="decimal" value={'.'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="equals" value={'='} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="clear" value={'clear'}  />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="add" value={'+'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="subtract" value={'-'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="multiply" value={'*'} />
                <Button onClick={handleClick} id="divide" value={'/'} />
            </div>
)

}
}
export default Calculator;
```

button class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
         <input type="button" value={props.value}/>

)
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
};


  handleClick(event){
 const answer = event.target.id; 
 if(answer==="clear") {
        this.setState({value:[]})
      }
}




export default Button;
```

Comment: I think you're doing it all wrong. Why do you have ``handleClick``` outside the ```Calculator``` class? try moving it into the calculator class and add and try calling it from there. i.e ```onClick={handleClick}``` becomes ```onClick={this.handleClick}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handleClick is not defined in the Caculator class...

You probably want to move it from button.js to calculator.js anyway, since it is setting the Calculator's state.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: []}

 }
 
 handleClick = () => {
  // do whatever you want to do here
  }

render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display id="display" value={this.state.value} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="zero" value={'0'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="one" value={'1'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="two" value={'2'}/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="three" value={'3'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="four" value={'4'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="five" value={'5'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="six" value={'6'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="seven" value={'7'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="eight" value={'8'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="nine" value={'9'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="decimal" value={'.'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="equals" value={'='} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="clear" value={'clear'}  />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="add" value={'+'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="subtract" value={'-'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="multiply" value={'*'} />
                <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="divide" value={'/'} />
            </div>
)

}
}
export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

So not the code but the actual error. Im super confused on what you are having issues with...

Comment: I solved it: just needed to get the handleclick outside the constructor. Thanks anyway!